# React Hooks trying to useState in array ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to work with Hooks in react but i have a doubt about useState and References. My problem is because i want to create multiple references in my jsx but i dont know how use the usestate like a Array, well in the insert of the usestate data.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import AOS from "aos";
import "./css/App.css";
import "aos/dist/aos.css";
import Skills from "./Components/Skills";
import Work from "./Components/Work";

const App = () => {
  const [ref, setRef] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    AOS.init({
      duration: 2000
    });
  });

  function handleOnClick(event) {
    ref.scrollIntoView();
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Row>
        <Col className="menu text-center" lg={4}>
          <div className="picture">
            <Image
              src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/Images/picture.jpg"}
              roundedCircle
            />
          </div>

          <h1 className="menu-name">Fulanito Detal</h1>

          <h4 className="menu-office">Software Engineer - Web Developer</h4>

          <div>
            <Row>
              <Col lg={3}></Col>
              <Col lg={6} className="menu-text">
                <ListGroup>
                  <ListGroup.Item
                    onClick={event => handleOnClick(event)}
                    active
                  >
                    ABOUT
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                  <ListGroup.Item>WORK EXPERIENCE</ListGroup.Item>
                  <ListGroup.Item>EDUCATION</ListGroup.Item>
                  <ListGroup.Item>SKILLS</ListGroup.Item>
                  <ListGroup.Item>CONTACT</ListGroup.Item>
                </ListGroup>
              </Col>
              <Col lg={3}></Col>
            </Row>
          </div>
        </Col>

        <Col className="info text-center" lg={8}>
          <Container>
            <div className="about"></div>

            <div
              className="work"
              ref={ref => {
                setRef(ref);
              }}
            >
              <Work />
            </div>

            <div className="education"></div>

            <div
              className="skills"
              ref={ref => {
                setRef(ref);
              }}
            >
              <Skills />
            </div>

            <div className="contact"></div>
          </Container>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The ref works fine just with one. If clicked about redirect to skills, but i want to use state like array to work with all references but i'm stuck with this one. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why not use the [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook designed for working with `ref`s?

Comment: Do you need to have menu items generated dynamically? or are they static? If it's static, you can declare one `ref` per each menu item. If it needs to be dynamic, it requires a bit more effort.

Comment: I try to used but doest work when  try current.focus(). For sure was a my mistake but i  cant find a solution. The menu items are static.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks. I will reply with the static nature in mind. ------- NVM. @skovy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57839157/4035) below is exactly what I was going for

Comment: thanks anyway! Really appreciate the help

Comment: You can use an array of refs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simplified example of using the [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const work = React.useRef();
  const skills = React.useRef();

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => work.current.scrollIntoView()}>
        WORK EXPERIENCE
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => skills.current.scrollIntoView()}>SKILLS</button>
      <div className="another" />
      <div className="work" ref={work}>
        WORK SECTION
      </div>
      <div className="skills" ref={skills}>
        SKILL SECTIONS
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit react-use-ref-scroll]